# cannot find symbol - class World

Tags: java, class

I'm doing something for a class of mine and this demo doesn't run. I don't know enough about Java to have any clue why really. This was setup by the teacher and so I would expect it to run.

```
import java.awt.Color;
public class TurtleGraphicsDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        World worldObj = new World();                   //create a World object to draw in

        Turtle myrtle = new Turtle(50, 50, worldObj);   //create a Turtle object to do the drawing

        //triangle with x,y points
        int x1 = 50;
        int y1 = 50;               //screen coordinates for first position
        int x2 = 50;
        int y2 = 100;              //screen coordinates for second position
        int x3 = 300;
        int y3 = 100;             //screen coordinates for third

        //prepare the Turtle object to draw
        myrtle.penUp();                     //pick up the pen to avoid leaving a trail when moving the turtle
        myrtle.setColor(Color.RED);         //set myrtle's color to red
        myrtle.moveTo(x1, y1);              //move to coordinate (50,50)
        myrtle.penDown();                   //put the pen down to start drawing

        //use the Turtle object to draw the triangle
        myrtle.moveTo(x2, y2);              //move to coordinate (50,100)
        myrtle.moveTo(x3, y3);
        myrtle.moveTo(x1, y1);              //move myrtle back to coordinate (50,50)

        System.out.println(worldObj);       //show some information about the world
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to import the turtle libraries? Look at your text book or notes for information on this.

Comment: That's what i would think too but this is the demo he gave to us as if it should run as is. I'll double check though

Comment: I don't do turtle graphics, so I'm not familiar with the library, but double-triple check the import statements at the top.

Comment: No that's definitely all there is to it. According to come quick research I think I need this statement import ch.aplu.turtle.*; but I get package doesn't exist

Comment: I figured it out. I asked the teacher and it turns out i needed to download something from the announcements i didn't read. Haha, thanks for your help though

Comment: Glad you've got it figured out, since that's what really matters.